# qsort with array of structs?

Tags: c++, struct, qsort

I am trying to use `qsort` on an array of structs but I get this error: expected primary-expression before '*' token

```
struct muchie {
    int x,y,c;
} a[100];

int cmp(const void* p, const void* q)
{
    muchie vp,vq;
    vp=*(muchie* p);
    vq=*(muchie* q);
    return vp.c-vq.c;
}

// ....

qsort(a,m,sizeof(muchie),cmp);
```

Comment: Provide correct cast operators: `(muchie*)`

Comment: Just use `std::sort`, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The casting of the parameters is wrong - should be `*(muchie*)p` instead of `*(muchie* p)`.

Use:

```
int cmp(const void* p, const void* q)
{
    muchie vp,vq;
    vp=*(muchie*) p;
    vq=*(muchie*) q;
    return vp.c-vq.c;
}
```

Comment: Oh, boy! Thanks a lot for pointing that out! I've been staring at the screen for a while!

Comment: @rptoma - No problem, glad to help.